# WPF - Bind vector image to Enhanced Tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my MainWindow I have a toolbar with a series of buttons.
Each button displays an icon which is a vector image converted from Inkscape in the form:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Canvas>
        <Geometry .../>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

All the icons are stored in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myIcon">
    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas>
            <Geometry .../>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

and assigned to the relevant button through a ContentPresenter:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <myDependencyProperties:EnhancedTooltip Header="Main" Style="{StaticResource EnhancedTooltip}" Content="Main Page"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <Button.Content>
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myIcon}"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

My Enhanced Tooltip control should display, among others, the icon of the parent button (as it's the case for some buttons within MS Office Ribbon).
I've tried a few ways to bind the content of the tooltip, adding a label or a button and binding its content to the one of the button, like in:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=ManyDifferentAttempts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
```

No need to say that I failed.
I also tried to assign the icon to the button through styles as in:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <myDependencyProperties:EnhancedTooltip Header="Main" Style="{StaticResource EnhancedTooltip}" Content="Main Page"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource myIcon}"/>
</Button>
```

where the icons are of course stored as Styles:

```
<Style x:Key="myIcon" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Geometry .../>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and added a Content Control (label or button) to the EnhancedTooltip to mimic the parent button behaviour by binding its ContentPresenter Style to the one of the parent button.
Without any success.

I could easily reach my goal when I used an image (png) as the icon for my button:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <myDependencyProperties:EnhancedTooltip Header="Main" Style="{StaticResource EnhancedTooltip}" Content="Main Page"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <Image Source="PathToMyPNGImage"/>
</Button>
```

and, in my EnhancedTooltip style:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Content.Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}} }"/>
```

How can I reach the same result now that I decided to use a vector image instead?
I can easily go back to the previous approach, but I'd like to learn something new.

Thank you for your time.

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just show a geometry.

Use a path.

Set or bind it's data to one of your geometries.

Lose the viewbox - and probably the canvas. Make the path content if you have a contentcontrol.

Set stretch to fill on the path.

I'd prefer to have a re-usable template if this is a common requirement and an attached property for the geometry.  But this is the quick and dirty version to give you the idea of what I have in mind.

```
    <Button x:Name="myButton"
            Tag="{StaticResource Star}"
            >
        <Button.Content>
            <Path Fill="Blue"
                  Data="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <Path Fill="Blue"
                      Data="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}"/>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Andy, thank you for your comment and sorry for the late reply (I've been busy at work). I tried to follow your advice, but I don't get how to actually bind the vector image (being it a canvas or a geometry) used as the content of my button to my tooltip content. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Andy, once again thank you for your time. I used your idea of setting the Tag property for the Button equal to the StaticResource with the data for my vector image (no need to have it as Path, I could leave it as Canvas). Then I've bound the ContentTemplate of the ContentPresenter of my Tooltip to the Tag property of the Ancestor of Type Button. It worked fine. Thumbs up for your idea.